# Showing error for MODE_PRIVATE within fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Showing error while using MODE_PRIVATE for sharedPreferences within onCreateView

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_package_categories, container, false);
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PackageType", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("package_categories_id", position);
    editor.commit();
    return layout;
    }
```

Comment: Should be `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_package_categories, container, false);
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PackageType", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("package_categories_id", position);
        editor.commit();
        return layout;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add context in your code like :

SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PackageType", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);